# Copy a linkedlist with an arbitrary pointer

Tags: java, linked-list

The full question description is found http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-linked-list-with-next-and-arbit-pointer/.
Looking for code review, optimization, clean code etc.

```
public class CopyArbit<T> {

    private Node<T> first;
    private Node<T> last;
    private int size;

    public CopyArbit() {}

    private static class Node<T> {
        T item;
        Node<T> next;
        Node<T> arbit;

        Node(T item, Node<T> next, Node<T> arbit) {
             this.item = item;
             this.next = next;
             this.arbit = arbit;
        }
    }

    public void add(T item) {
        final Node<T> l = last;
        final Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(item, null, null);
        last = newNode;
        if (first == null) {
            first = newNode;
        } else {
            l.next = newNode;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void makeArbitrary (int srcPos, int destPos) {
        if (first == null) throw new NoSuchElementException("Linkedlist is empty.");

        if (srcPos > size || srcPos < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The srcPos  " + srcPos + " is out of bound");
        }

        if (destPos > size || destPos < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The destPos  " + destPos + " is out of bound");
        }

        Node<T> source =  getNodeAtPos(srcPos); 
        Node<T> destination =  getNodeAtPos(destPos);

        source.arbit = destination;
    }

    private Node<T> getNodeAtPos(int posFromStart) {
        assert posFromStart > 0 && posFromStart <= size;

        /*
         * We need (posFromStart - 1) hops to reach the node at that pos.
         */
        int hops = posFromStart - 1;
        int counter = 0;

        Node<T> temp = first;

        while (counter < hops) {
            temp = temp.next;
            counter++;
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public CopyArbit<T> getCopy() {
        Node<T> temp = first;

        // interject nodes in between each other.
        // ie convert A->B->C->D into A->A->B->B->C->C->D->D
        while (temp != null) {
            Node<T> tempAux = new Node<T>(temp.item, temp.next, null);
            temp.next = tempAux;
            temp =  temp.next.next;
        }

        // fill in the arbit pointer
        temp = first;
        while (temp != null) {
            Node<T> tempAux = temp.next;
            tempAux.arbit = temp.arbit.next;
            temp = temp.next.next;
        }

        return split();
    }

    private CopyArbit<T> split () {
        Node<T> temp = first;

        Node<T> first = null;
        Node<T> firstHead = null;
        Node<T> second = null;
        Node<T> secondHead = null;

        int counter = 0;

        while (temp != null) {
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                if (firstHead == null) {
                    firstHead = temp;
                } else {
                    first.next = temp;
                }
                first = temp;
            } else {
                if (secondHead == null) {
                    secondHead = temp;
                } else {
                    second.next = temp;
                }
                second = temp;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
            counter++;
        }
        first.next = null; // note this step.

        CopyArbit<T> copyArbit = new CopyArbit<T>();
        copyArbit.first = secondHead;
        copyArbit.last = second;
        copyArbit.size = size;

        return copyArbit;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new LinkedListIterator();
    }

    private class LinkedListIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        int currentSize;
        Node<T> node;

        LinkedListIterator() {
            currentSize = 0;
            node = first;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentSize < size;
        }

        public T next() {
            T item = node.item;
            node = node.next;
            currentSize++;
            return item;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    public Iterator<T> arbitIterator() {
        return new LinkedListArbitIterator();
    }

    private class LinkedListArbitIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        int currentSize;
        Node<T> node;

        LinkedListArbitIterator() {
            currentSize = 0;
            node = first;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentSize < size;
        }

        public T next() {
            T item = node.arbit.item;
            node = node.next;
            currentSize++;
            return item;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CopyArbit<Integer> source = new CopyArbit<Integer>();
        source.add(10);
        source.add(20);
        source.add(30);
        source.add(40);

        source.makeArbitrary(1, 4);
        source.makeArbitrary(2, 1);
        source.makeArbitrary(3, 4);
        source.makeArbitrary(4, 2);

        CopyArbit<Integer> target = source.getCopy();

        System.out.println("Expected: 40 10 40 20");
        System.out.print("Actual: ");

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = target.arbitIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. I'd move the `main` method to a separate class. (For example, `CopyArbitMain`.) It's usually a good idea to separate a class from its clients.
2. `Iterator.remove()` should throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if remove is not supported ([according to the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29)). Anyway, `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` comments usually a bad smell, don't leave them in the code.
3. Instead of

   ```
   if (srcPos > size || srcPos < 1) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("The srcPos  " + srcPos + " is out of bound");
   }
   ```

   you could use [Guava's `checkArgument`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkArgument%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) (or just create a similar method, if you don't want to include an external library):

   ```
   checkArgument(srcPos > size || srcPos < 1, "The srcPos %s is out of bound", srcPos);
   ```

   It's a little bit simpler and easier to read.